# Can not find the shared library:libhdfs3.so

Tags: anaconda, distributed, dask, blaze

everyone. I'm try to used Dask with Distributed + HDFS for processing some files. when I installed the distributed try to install the HDFS3 plugins, the error was :

`Can not find the shared library:libhdfs3.so`

My environment is Ubuntu 16 Desktop version. I strict according to bewlo, but still not working. Hope someone can help! Thanks a lot

```
conda install hdfs3 -c conda-forge
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/wangzw/deb trusty contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray-wangzw-deb.list
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhdfs3 libhdfs3-dev
pip install hdfs3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answers this question and I figure out the solution by myself , at least it works for me.

```
conda install libhdfs3
pip install libhdfs3
conda install -c clinicalgraphics libgcrypt11
conda install libprotobuf=2.5
conda update libhdfs3
```

if still not work try to update.
[image]

Comment: Why you need to install `libhdfs3` with conda **AND** with pip?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using conda and you are using **pip**, you can also face this error

> Can not find the shared library:libhdfs3.so

To ensure requirements in this page https://github.com/ContinuumIO/libhdfs3-downstream/tree/master/libhdfs3

solved my problem.

There are packages that you should install, if you are installing with **pip**:

- cmake (2.8+)                    http://www.cmake.org/
- boost (tested on 1.53+)         http://www.boost.org/
- google protobuf                 http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/
- libxml2                         http://www.xmlsoft.org/
- kerberos                        http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/
- libuuid                         http://sourceforge.net/projects/libuuid/
- libgsasl                        http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/ (need https://github.com/bdrosen96/libgsasl)
  openssl                         https://www.openssl.org/

  P.S.: OS: Centos7